# Share internet connection over RJ45 to a modem with phone line input

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, modem

I need to make a very specific test, this is not for general use, I know it can be slow.

I have a Playstation 2 and bought a old usb modem that was used before Sony release the Network Adapter with RJ45 input.

This modem has a phone line input and a phone output like old modems.

I would like to use it to connect to internet but without using a real phone line, and sharing my connection using a RJ45 from my default router, there's some adapter or other device that can do it?

I found some adapter on amazon and aliexpress, but there's no much information in how it works.

Comment: An actual modem with analog RJ11 input/ouput needs an actual analog phone line.  It itself is what does the translation from analog to/from digital.  To connect a (digital) line from your router you would need a network adapter.

Comment: You would need to emulate a Dial-Up/DSL ISP. That is possible, but cumbersome. A cheap adapter from RJ45 to RJ11 will not work. A quick Google search reveals [this guide](https://dogemicrosystems.ca/wiki/Dial-up_pool) (follow at your own risk, I have not read nor sponsor its contents).

Comment: Can you show the adapter you have (model as well)?

Comment: hi @u1686_grawity this one https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/PRkAAOSwSgNiRXe6/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: nice @ComputerUser121212 i have a raspberrypi, I will take a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A USB-[RJ11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ11) phone modem such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T1C8Y5F) can be used on PC's which have the proper drivers, e.g., those used by Windows *Phone Service*. The modem phone connection must be to a [POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) copper line that matches the modem's locale. For example, in the USA, the standard is ~600 Ω line, 48 VDC open circuit, ~100 VAC ring signal, etc.

To connect *two* devices requires *two* modems and a line simulator, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004PXK314). In the days of the [Atari 8-bit computers](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Atari_8-bit_family) computers, I made a small 48 VDC supply, with 600 Ω series resistor, to connect two 800XL's with their respective modems, at ~600 bps.

Whether you'd find the throughput of modems sufficient is one question you'd need to answer; ~50 kbps being max for POTS.  Whether the Playstation 2 has phone modem drivers is another question.

BTW, I do find a phone modem useful on rare occasion to send a fax, rather than go through an online service to do so.